# Как написать редактор с нуля и что для этого понадобится знать?

Tags: c++, редактор, sdl, редактор-текста, sdl2

Как написать текстовой редактор (редактор кода) имея минимум средств, т.е. с графической стороны у меня будет возможность только :

- Рендер текста в точке (x, y)
- Рисование графических примитивов (точка, линия, круг, изображение, ...)

Т.е. в наборе инструментов не будет виджетов типа `TextBox`, `textarea` и т.п. Хотя я не отказался бы от кнопок и меню.

Т.е. мне придется самому организовать все элементы интерфейса. Например, курсор я буду рисовать с помощью `drawLine(x, y, x, y + heightOfCursor)`.

Это нужно для того, чтобы иметь больший контроль над текстом.

Подскажите какую лучше всего использовать библиотеку и какой язык. Было бы здорово чтобы у языка и библиотеки были высокая производительность.

С чего лучше начать?

P.S. Думаю использовать C++ и SDL, но может есть вариант лучше?

Comment: http://rsdn.ru/res/book/cpp/halpern.xml https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ed вот кратенько литра

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCZawXfOaJwj5gmYM5HrufXw/videos Может быть, вам поможет.

Comment: @Akuma925, в книжке, я так понял, консольный редактор?

Comment: В кинге описанно как сторить текстовые интерфейсы

Comment: Возможно, стоит убрать из вопроса части о "посоветуйте книги/статьи/библиотеки", [потому что это оффтопик](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) и может послужить причиной закрытия вопроса. Остальное вроде ок.